# flex : regular expression for accepting only numbers, letters , white spaces

Tags: regex, flex4.5

I want to write a regular expression to check string that contains only letters,digits,spaces,#  and the string length should be minimum 10 and maximum 29 and string should not begin with blank.

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible regular expression, but I don't know flex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9#][a-zA-Z0-9 #]{9,28}$/
```